# What is the Apache URL Rewrite rule for my .htaccess file for this IIS rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is the IIS rule:

```
            <rule name="Pin">
                <match url="^pin/([^]+)/" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="pin.php?id={R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

What would this look like in a .htaccess file for Apache?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^pin/([^]+)/ pin.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This really should be pretty easy for you by now. The `<match url="">` value goes into the rule's first parameter, the `<action>`'s url value goes into the rule's second parameter, replacing any `{R:#}`'s with `$#`'s, and add a `[L]` flag at the end, if necessary.

Comment: I am getting this error when using that rewrite rule. Any ideas why I'd get this? `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@disneypinplace.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: @EthanAllen Sounds like you have `Multiviews` turned on, you need to add `Options -Multiviews` somewhere in your htaccess file. Either that, or this rule is conflicting with something else in your htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is same regex problem causing `500` this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pin/([^/]+)/$ /pin.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```